# Admob Test Ads load, Live Ads will not

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm trying to implement admob ads as follows:

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

when I use the test device ID I can see the test ad, however when I use the above code the ad is not visible. This is the log I see when the above code runs:

```
06-14 17:15:15.486 23521-23521/com.nick.app I/Ads: Starting ad request.
06-14 17:15:15.487 23521-23521/com.nick.app I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("**********************") to get test ads on this device.
06-14 17:15:18.356 23521-23521/com.nick.app E/Ads: JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined (:1)
06-14 17:15:18.449 23521-23521/com.nick.app I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
06-14 17:15:18.477 23521-23521/com.nick.app E/Ads: JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined (:1)
```

Any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `adUnitID` in my `AdView` defined in my xml layout needed to match what was defined in my Activity where I was defining the ad.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. Your answer not clear for me. Could you please tell me how you managed to get it work? I have defined 'adUnitID' only in layout XML inside the 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView'

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too at first, you have to wait a little bit. It should show within a few hours, probably less.

Answer (score 0):

```
 MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
```

This above code should not contain the banner ad unit id. You should place  YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID as a second parameter as givern below

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID");
```